# Get a socket reference in different namespace

Tags: node.js, socket.io

As title, how can i get a reference to socket in different namespace?

Below code, show how to get socket reference in socket.io v0.9 but not in latest one v1.3.7

```
var chatInfra = io.of("/chat_infra").on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
    var comSocket = chatCom.sockets[socket.id]; //<-- this work in socket.io v0.9
    comSocket.join(room.name);
});

var chatCom = io.of("/chat_com").on( 'connection', function( socket ) {
 //code
});
```